# Internal energy for Phase Transitions

Tags: thermodynamics, phase, heat, temperature, sublimation

Can we justify that "For sublimation of a solid at 1 atm  $\Delta U>0$ at low temperature and $\Delta U<0$ at high temperature?"

I read several answers and came to know that $U=f(T)$ is valid only for ideal gases at $\pu{1 atm}$ pressure where $T$ is temperature.

Internal energy is the sum of kinetic energy of molecules and chemical potential energy of molecules.

For phase transition even if the temperature remains constant, its internal energy changes.

I tried  to justify  by considering that while sublimation as solid changes to gases its degrees of freedom increases and we may say internal energy is a function of degrees of freedom so  as temperature increases so $U_2 > U_1$ so $\Delta U >0$ but this contradicts what we have to prove.

Also similarly what can  we say about internal energy for other phase transitions ?

[image]

Answer given is: ABCD

source:[Physical Chemistry (Vol. II) (Class XI) Chemistry Module For JEE (Main+Advanced) Paperback – 1 January 2018
by Resonance Eduventures Limited](https://www.amazon.in/Physical-Chemistry-Class-Module-Advanced/dp/B07DKX9JNJ/ref=pd_vtp_14_7?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B07DKX9JNJ&pd_rd_r=699c4843-87c7-4360-a892-3dd29ed68839&pd_rd_w=EkEVU&pd_rd_wg=4iKHo&pf_rd_p=1605a9ef-9762-49bc-b130-0216f64a8e27&pf_rd_r=8CSQSF00SFJY1G44C182&psc=1&refRID=8CSQSF00SFJY1G44C182)

Answer (score 2):

> Can we justify that "For sublimation of a solid at 1 atm  $\Delta U>0$ at low temperature and $\Delta U<0$ at high temperature?"

**No.**

$\Delta U>0$, always, for sublimation, because of the energy needed to separate the atoms or molecules in changing from the solid to the gas phase.

As for the enthalpy,

$$H = U +PV \Rightarrow \Delta H = \Delta U+\Delta (PV)=\Delta U+ P\Delta V+ V \Delta P$$

Thus at constant pressure:

$$\Delta H = \Delta U+ P\Delta V \approx  \Delta U+ nRT$$

[Here I've used the ideal gas law to approximate the volume of the gas, and ignored the volume of the solid, which (at 1 atm, room temperature) is about 3 orders of magnitude smaller.]

I.e., $\Delta H$ will be *even more positive* than $\Delta U$, because of the pV-work required to make space for the gas.

The reason why sublimation becomes more favorable as the temperature increases is because sublimation has a positive $\Delta S$, and $\Delta G = \Delta H - T \Delta S$.  But, irrespective of temperature, at any temperature and pressure at which the solid can exist,  $\Delta U_{solid->gas} >0 $.

$\Delta U >0$ for liquid->gas and solid->liquid phase transitions as well (with the possible exception of the solid->liquid phase transitions for helium-3 and helium-4 at extremely low temperatures which, at least according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_fusion, have $\Delta H < 0$; but solid helium doesn't exist at the 1 atm pressure specified by the OP).

*Yes, you might be able to come up some extreme hypothetical mechanical system where the solid is under such great pressure that the intermolecular forces are so far into the repulsive part of their potentials that $\Delta U_{solid->gas} <0 $.  But that's clearly not what the OP had in mind, since s/he specified 1 atm.  And, in addition, such an arrangement would require that only the solid, but not the gas, be at that extreme pressure.  So, strictly speaking, that $\Delta U$ would not be for the sublimation alone, it would be for the sublimation plus the pressure change.

Comment: btw I got this question in my textbook which was a multiple choice question which said "for sublimation of a solid at 1 atm,which of the following **may** be correct" and options    $\Delta U >0$ at low temperature,$\Delta U < 0$ at high temperature were given correct,so did they necessarily meant extreme hypothetical conditions?

Comment: @user69608  Can you give a complete reference to the textbook, and a screenshot of the problem and answer?

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 1):

> Can we justify that "For sublimation of a solid at 1 atm  $\Delta U>0$ at low temperature and $\Delta U<0$ at high temperature?"

A justification can be suggested by writing

$$\Delta_{\mathrm{sub}} U = \Delta _{\mathrm{sub}} H - RTn$$

(but in retrospect it has a flaw, see below). If you assume the enthalpy of sublimation is approximately constant (weakly dependent on T) then it is clear that to sublimate a constant amount of substance n requires an input of energy at low T (in the form of input heat $q_p = \Delta _{\mathrm{sub}} H$ to break bonds in the solid lattice) but results in a net reduction in internal energy of the system (due to work done on expansion) at sufficiently high T.

As hinted at in another answer, however, this justification has one flaw*. The flaw is that (in the constant pressure scenario) heat input provides energy not only to break bonds, but also to drive the expansion of the gas (perform work). In the isochoric (constant volume) scenario there is no work and $\Delta U = q_V$.  In the isobaric (constant pressure) scenario the sum of the additional energy input as heat (>0) to perform expansion work and energy loss due to the expansion work (<0) cancel, so these changes do not alter $\Delta U$.

It should be noted that $\Delta _{\mathrm{sub}} H>0$ (sublimation is endothermic).

It is interesting to note that in the case of vaporization the enthalpy drops to zero as T nears the critical point. Similarly the expansion work required drops to zero near the critical point.

*I thought there was an additional flaw, but haven't figured it out entirely.

Comment: What if for a solid  at high temperature $\Delta  H$ is sufficiently greater than  $RTn$ then $\Delta U$ would come positive which contradicts.?

Comment: Can you answer the  other questions in the post?

Comment: You can argue along the same lines for the liquid-vapor transition. In that case the $\Delta H$ also decreases with increasing T because of the relative heat capacities of the two phases. For the liquid-solid transition it is a little less obvious what to expect. The pV expansion term for melting is much smaller than for vaporization or sublimation. It can be negative (eg water) or positive (most pure substances). The pV term is presumably dominated by the enthalpy term which increases with increasing T (because the liquid has the greater heat capacity).

Comment: And why degrees of freedom thing  fails?

Comment: As your question shows, at low T condensed phases are lower energy states then vapor phases, but they are also lower in entropy (I suppose that's what you mean by degrees of freedom, the number of microstates available to the system, which is usually described using the entropy).

Comment: @BuckThorn  This is incorrect.  The extra energy needed to do pV-expansion work at higher temperature does not reduce $\Delta U$, which is the amount of energy needed to separate the molecules plus their increase in kinetic energy due to the increased degrees of freedom as they go from solid to gas. Rather, the expansion work is added to $\Delta U$, which is itself always positive for sublimation.

Comment: @theorist during an expansion the system does work, so the change in energy is negative

Comment: @BuckThorn There are two issues here.  The first is $\Delta H$ vs $\Delta U$: This is a sublimation, so it's at constant T.  Imagine an endothermic process (reaction, phase change, doesn't matter) at constant T & V.  q_v = $\Delta U$. Now suppose we switch to constant p, and further suppose the reactant is a solid and the product is a gas.  More heat (q_p) will need to flow into the reactant mixture (equal to $p \Delta V$) because now we additionally need to do the work to expand the system. Look at the math:  $\Delta H = \Delta U + p \Delta V$.  The pV term is positive, not negative.

Comment: But the first issue ($\Delta H$ vs $\Delta U$) is incidental to the question, which is what is happening with $\Delta U$.  Think about it physically -- you are pulling molecules apart.  $\Delta U$ can't be negative, irrespective of whether you have to add or subtract pV to get $\Delta H$ (though you do have to add pV:  $\Delta H = \Delta U + p \Delta V$).   The pV term only affects  $\Delta H$.  It has no effect on $Delta U$.

Comment: @theorist Well, I've come around to agreeing that the "justification" in my answer has a flaw, and you point in the right direction, but I think you miss that $\Delta U = q + w$ so that w very much affects $\Delta U$. Looking at $\Delta U = q_v$ is an interesting alternative but difficult to imagine: how do you transition from liquid to gas without providing molecules with more room?

Comment: BTW I think that's what happens at the critical point (there is no change in density so no work is done).

Comment: We're doing this at constant temperature, so any pV work required by doing this at constant p is cancelled out by increased heat flow into the system, leaving $\Delta U$ unaffected by the pV work.  That increased heat flow due to pV work at constant p accounts for nearly all the difference between $\Delta H$ and $\Delta U$*. [*There will be a slight effect on$\Delta U$ from the p-dependence of the internal energy of the solid, but that is small.]

And you can carry out sublimation at constant V by putting  a solid into an evacuated container.

Comment: But the most important thing is to think physically about $\Delta U$ --think of these intermolecular associations that hold the molecules in a solid together as potential wells, and you are bringing the molecules out of those potential wells as you separate them into the gas phase. So the internal energy can't go down when you do this (assuming this is purely a phase transition, and you aren't changing the identity of the molecules themselves).

Comment: @theorist the question asks for a justification for or against the proposition, and the choice remains whether to use a purely thermodynamic argument or to appeal to questions about microscopic behavior. While you can unquestionably argue based on stat mech (number of microstates etc) I like that thermodynamics can provide a justification. I admit that my initial one was misleading but it's interesting why. The reason is that $\Delta U<0$ would violate the second law.

Comment: Your initial justification wasn't "misleading", it was simply incorrect.  I believe characterizing it as "misleading" obfuscates things, making it confusing for other readers to follow this.  And I'm afraid your new justification is also incorrect.  This has nothing to do with the 2nd law. The fundamental flaw in your argument is that you "assume the enthalpy of sublimation is approximately constant (weakly dependent on T)", and then proceed to infer changes in $\Delta U$ based on a changing (with temp) value for $nRT$ subtracted from an approximately constant (with T) $\Delta H$....

Comment: ....But this is completely backwards!  The $nRT$ term is a pV-work term, and thus affects $\Delta H$, not $\Delta U$!  Hence it makes no sense to talk about changing T as having an effect via an $nRT$ term, and then to say $\Delta H$ is approximately constant with T.  Again, your entire argument is based on the $nRT$ creating a temperature-dependence in $\Delta U$, but that temperature-dependence is in $\Delta H$, not $\Delta U$.  I.e., you are creating a fallacious T-dependence in $\Delta U$.

Comment: @theorist You bring up some interesting points worth taking into consideration. Thanks for your helpful input!

Comment: Perhaps we should ask @ChetMiller for arbitration. I know my original justification was flawed (but your arguments against it do not seem quite right either) and I am still working to construct a cycle to show that the second law is violated but it's dawning on me that this will be a challenge. Your own justification is partly based on a hand-wavy molecular description ("degrees of freedom"?) which is intuitively satisfying and yet not rigorous. Chet displays a clear mind about these problems and has broad experience based on which to judge. Maybe he can be of help?

Comment: You are right that my degrees of freedom argument was not a good one, so I've deleted it.  I will endeavour to come up with a better one, based on the temperature-dependence of $\Delta U$ for sublimation, perhaps this weekend.  I sometimes disagree with Chet Miller on thermodynamics, so I would not view him as an acceptable arbitrator.  I might suggest Karsten Theis, but let's hold off until I work on this more.